# Match Column 1 to Column 2, Display Result in Column Three that is next to Column 2 Match

Tags: indexing, match

I am looking for an Excel spreadsheet where I am trying to find where one field in column 1 matches a field in column two and spits out the text entry in column 3 that is next next to the match from column 2. They are the same type of field named 'ProjectID', a 5 digit number.

They do not match on the row level because columns 2 and 3 were pasted in from another spreadsheet that contained correlations between **ProjectID** and **Benchmark Definition**. Column 1 represents the ProjectID field from the original data extract that did not include the Benchmark definition.

So to recap, I want this formula to look at the ProjectID in column 1, find a match somewhere in Column 2, and spit out the Benchmark definition that is next to the corresponding match. Keep in mind this match will not necessarily be on the same row as the respective column 1 ProjectID.

I tried this formula from another question but couldn't get it to work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGDG.png)

Comment: Could you please add an example of the relevant data from the spreadsheet, this could make your question easier to understand.

Comment: The first two columns which are labeled ProjectID are just 5 digit numbers, and the third column (Benchmark) is just a text entry.